Sum POSIXct POSIXt values from a column
I have one data frame with more than 1000 rows, and I have one column duracao which I want to sum the values that have there HH:MM, and resulting also the value as HH:MM.
df <- data.frame(duracao = c("00:29", "00:26", "00:38"))

#The sum should be 01:33


First I tried:
class(df$duracao)
>character

df$duracao<-as.numeric(df$duracao)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(duracao = seconds_to_period(duracao * 86400))

df <- df %>% #aqui
  mutate(duracao = sprintf("%02d:%02d", hour(duracao), minute(duracao)))

total_duracao <- sum(df$duracao)


Then second try:
df$duracao <- as.POSIXct(df$duracao, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC")
df <- df %>%
  mutate(duracao_sec = as.numeric(duracao - as.POSIXct("1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")))
total_seconds <- sum(df$duracao_sec)                                  
total_hours <- total_seconds %/% 3600
total_minutes <- (total_seconds %% 3600) %/% 60
total_duracao <- sprintf("%02d:%02d", total_hours, total_minutes)
print(total_duracao)

Update
I found these weird values in the column
I ran this code

which(!grepl("\\d{2}:\\d{2}", df$duracao))

And the values were:

 -1:-20 , -1:-00 and -1:-11


it should be 1:20, 1:00 and 1:11, how can I change it, please?

Should the sum be 01:35 or 01:33?

Hi, it’s 01:33 sorry

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df |>
  mutate(duracao = gsub("-", "", duracao, fixed = TRUE),
         period = as.duration(hm(duracao))) |>
  summarize(period = seconds_to_period(sum(period)),
            hh_mm = paste0(sum(day(period * 24) + hour(period)), ":", minute(period)))
#      period hh_mm
# 1 1H 33M 0S  1:33

If you don't want the values in a data frame then you can simply use this pipe chain (and ignore the library(dplyr) statement):
library(lubridate)

df$duracao |>
  gsub("-", "", x = _, fixed = TRUE) |>
  hm() |>
  as.duration() |>
  sum() |>
  seconds_to_period()

Note that this returns a Period object. This makes it easy to extract components if you need:
total_duracao <- df$duracao |>
  gsub("-", "", x = _, fixed = TRUE) |>
  hm() |>
  as.duration() |>
  sum() |>
  seconds_to_period()

hour(total_duracao)
# [1] 1

minute(total_duracao)
# [1] 33

second(total_duracao)
# [1] 0


Hi LMc, I want to see the result in HH:MM you did with the duracao as character?, and I tried the first code, but resulted in: # A tibble: 1 × 1
period

1 NA
Warning message:
There was 1 warning in mutate().
ℹ In argument: period = as.duration(hm(duracao)).
Caused by warning in .parse_hms():
! Some strings failed to parse

@ÉrikaSoaresCoelho Without seeing more of your data, my guess is that you have some strings that are not in HH:MM format.

How can I check that? If is not HH:MM format? there is more than 1000 rows, the value is as.character

which(!grepl("\\d{2}:\\d{2}", df$duracao)) will return the row indices that do not match the pattern HH:MM.

Yeah, I found these values -1:-20 , -1:-00 and -1:-11, it should be 1:20, 1:00 and 1:11 , how can I change it, please?

@ÉrikaSoaresCoelho Please update your post with these invalid values and I will edit my answer.

LMc, done! I updated!

@ÉrikaSoaresCoelho I added a gsub() command. Since your values are character, you can simply use gsub() to delete the - if they exist in your data.

Hi LMc, the code worked but as I have a lot data, in my R, the first part of code is showing "49d 12H 36M 0S" and the second part of the code is showing `> hour(total_duracao)
[1] 12

minute(total_duracao)
[1] 36
second(total_duracao)
[1] 0. The result is hiding the total of effort. There is a way to show the result in HH:MM ? I mean, I need the result in HH:MM, it's possible to converting the days (whole data) to HH:MM? And the code df |>
mutate(period = as.duration(hm(duracao))) |>
summarize(period = seconds_to_period(sum(period)))` looks with the result in a better way


Sorry for the daly LMc, I'm currently working onboard a vessel and I was without internet

@ÉrikaSoaresCoelho Yes there is also a day() function. Simply extract the day information multiply it by 24 to convert it to hours. Take that amount an add it to the output from hour() and then you can use paste0 to join the HH to minutes with a :. I have shown this in the pipe chain as an example. Note: using paste0 to get it in that format will convert it to a character object, so typical time arithmetic and value extractions will not be possible.

One way is to convert your time strings into a POSIXct object and then substrate the start of the day in order to get the time difference.
df <- data.frame(duracao = c("00:29", "00:26", "00:38"))
 
#calculate the time difference from the time to the start of the day
Minutes <- as.difftime(df$duracao, "%H:%M", units="mins")
print(sum(Minutes))
#Time difference of 93 mins

Mins_int <- as.integer(sum(Minutes))
paste0(Mins_int%/% 60, ":", Mins_int%% 60)
#[1] "1:33"


Hi Dave2e, I tried this code, but results in > print(sum(Minutes)) Time difference of NA mins
